# Use Linear Layout in TableRow

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I try to make a table in my Android app with cells like this:

http://clip2net.com/s/iKPw39

(sorry for this link, I can't attach images due to low reputation)

My idea was to use a linear layout in a table row, but is not working correct.
Please, if you have any idea about how to modify the table layout to work as I expect - give me any idea.

**My xml code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        style="@style/TextColor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:textColor="@colors/white" >

        <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextColor"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/start_time" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextColor"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="@string/start_time" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextColor"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="@string/start_time" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextColor"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="@string/start_time" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
             <TextView
                style="@style/TextColor"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="@string/start_time" />
             <TextView
                style="@style/TextColor"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="@string/start_time" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="10"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="ADDS" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**
I made some changes according to your comments. Please, take a look and tell me please, why the text is not displayed?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        style="@style/TextColor"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:text="@string/start_time" />
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextColor"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:text="@string/activate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        style="@style/TextColor"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:text="@string/start_time" />
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextColor"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:text="@string/activate" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why u just use vertical linear layout ?

Comment: Post complete layout.

Comment: I'm new to the android development, so please, even if the question seems to be stupid, give me an advice.

Comment: If you jst need a Box with a border and inside it in vertical Two lines of text Just use a `LinearLayout` with `background` property set to a drawable that would draw the border.And then inside the `LinearLayout` with `orientatio=vertical` use two `TextView` with diferent font size.

Comment: Deb, I need a grid of 5x2 boxes. I'll try to make it with linear layouts now

Comment: check my answer ,may be it will help

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. 
I got an solution for my purpose.
My xml file looks like this now:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextColor"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:textSize="46sp"
                    android:text="@string/start_time" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextColor"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/zero"
                    android:text="@string/activate" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    style="@style/TextColor"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:textSize="46sp"
                    android:text="@string/start_time" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    style="@style/TextColor"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/activate" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/row">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />
        </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help. This row is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

For border place this in a file named border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

And to draw the inside content use this

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="Sample Text"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:text="Sample Text"/>
```

You can use the `LinearLayout` inside your `TableRow` or anywhere you want

Comment: can u tell me what problem u are facing?Is the problem view not at all visible?

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/iKR6Qj
Text is not displaying. Please, check the edited posts. I added code with linear layout.

Comment: in the `TextView` can u remove the `style` property and use `android:textColor="@color/white"`. U will need a white color in your colors.xml
`<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>`